# Ключевое слово async

Tags: c#, асинхронность

При ознакомлении с данным вопросом встретил такое определение:
Ключевое слово async  ...(еще несколько пунктов)
"Передает" результат метода или исключение вверх по стеку?
Что это значит? Что вообще происходит со стеком, выделенным потоку, после того, как встречается ключевое слово await перед незавершенным таском? Насколько я понимаю, поток может заняться выполнением других вещей, т.е. стек очищается? тогда как восстанавливается стек, на котором была вызвана async функция с await?

Comment: вы путаете стек потока и стек выполнения. На [скрине](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BHEN.png) вы видите работу 3 разных потоков, но при этом у исключения только один стек.